# RStudio Connect Failure to Retrieve Package when Deploying Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, rsconnect

I am trying to deploy a Shiny app on RStudio Connect. The deployment progresses until it tries to install the package, 'mvtnorm' from CRAN, at which point I get a 404 error, and the deployment fails.

I've tried the URL from the deployment logs: https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/mvtnorm, and I found that the version of mvtnorm that RSConnect is trying to install is not present in the archive. I've tried manually uninstalling and installing the required version of mvtnorm in the console (1.1-1), and I've tried setting my 'repos' option to a CRAN mirror (cloud.r-project.org) to see if that would help with the 404 error, but neither worked.

Any help would be appreciated! I don't know enough about RSConnect to identify whether this is a problem that can be solved locally or if I need to contact my RStudio server admin to update packages there.

As a final note, it looks like 'mvtnorm' is part of base R, but I don't use it in this app. If there is a way to remove it as a dependency and publish without that package, that would be OK too.

Here are my deployment logs:

```
----- Deployment log started at  2020-11-13 

09:18:14  -----
Deploy command: 
 rsconnect::deployApp(appDir = "~/GitHub/reprints-app", appFileManifest = "C:/Users/JAELLI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/8456-b43d-d6b8-889e",      account = "jacob_ellison", server = "knowledge.eng.kaplan.com",      appName = "reprints-app", appId = 49, launch.browser = function(url) {         message("Deployment completed: ", url)     }, lint = FALSE, metadata = list(asMultiple = FALSE, asStatic = FALSE),      logLevel = "verbose") 

Session information: 
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.0   rsconnect_0.8.16
Cookies: 
[1] "None"
GET /__api__/applications/49 120ms
----- Bundle upload started at  2020-11-13 09:18:15  -----
[2020-11-13 09:18:15] Inferring App mode and parameters 
[2020-11-13 09:18:15] Bundling app dir 
[2020-11-13 09:18:15] Generate manifest.json 
Warning in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  Unable to find repository URL for package foreign
[2020-11-13 09:19:46] Writing Rmd index if necessary 
[2020-11-13 09:19:46] Compressing the bundle 
POST /__api__/applications/49/upload 1480ms
[2020-11-13 09:19:48] Saving deployment record for reprints-app - jacob_ellison 
----- Server deployment started at  2020-11-13 09:19:48  -----
POST /__api__/applications/49/deploy 79ms
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=0 59ms
[Connect] Building Shiny application...
[Connect] Bundle requested R version 3.6.0; using /usr/lib/R/bin/R which has version 3.4.4
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=2 70ms
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:48.770475291 Using user agent string: 'RStudio R (3.4.4 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu x86_64 linux-gnu)' 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:49.294791978 Running on host: knowledge.eng.kaplan.com
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:49.305240888 linux distribution: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (bionic) 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:49.306859942 # Validating R library read / write permissions --------------------------------
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:49.307431195 R version: 3.4.4
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:49.320222696 # Validating managed packrat installation --------------------------------------
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:49.320763205 Vendored packrat archive: /opt/rstudio-connect/ext/R/packrat_0.5.0-26_8753d425f363c420846fe05bcba05e5e9b080bb5.tar.gz
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:49.335143669 Vendored packrat SHA: 8753d425f363c420846fe05bcba05e5e9b080bb5
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:49.337578652 Managed packrat SHA:  8753d425f363c420846fe05bcba05e5e9b080bb5
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:49.338751658 Managed packrat version: 0.5.0.26
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:49.340105377 Managed packrat is up-to-date.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:49.340889291 # Validating packrat cache read / write permissions ----------------------------
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=14 60ms
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:49.682453117 Audited package hashes with local packrat installation.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:49.738069897 # Installing required R packages with `packrat::restore()` ---------------------
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.544553291 Installing BH (1.72.0-3) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.557808097 Using cached BH.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.557970047     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.558132817 Installing DBI (1.1.0) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.697390748 Using cached DBI.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.697574829     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.697733894 Installing Formula (1.2-3) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.708535372 Using cached Formula.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.708693806     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.708878142 Installing MASS (7.3-51.4) ... 
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=26 50ms
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.723097313 Using cached MASS.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.723326800     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.723466160 Installing R6 (2.4.1) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.735397590 Using cached R6.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.735562553     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.735721506 Installing RColorBrewer (1.1-2) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.746403240 Using cached RColorBrewer.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.746575373     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.746729863 Installing Rcpp (1.0.4) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.760537251 Using cached Rcpp.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.760695556     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.760848264 Installing abind (1.4-5) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.771363694 Using cached abind.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.771519561     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.771668763 Installing acepack (1.4.1) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.782038951 Using cached acepack.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.782166411     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.782322383 Installing assertthat (0.2.1) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.793210206 Using cached assertthat.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.793380238     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.793537168 Installing backports (1.1.8) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.806455090 Using cached backports.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.806619902     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.806773253 Installing base64enc (0.1-3) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.817146682 Using cached base64enc.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.817311358     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.817469864 Installing clipr (0.7.0) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.831217869 Using cached clipr.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.831383709     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.831536497 Installing cluster (2.0.8) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.846529262 Using cached cluster.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.846691385     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.846848516 Installing codetools (0.2-16) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.858084189 Using cached codetools.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.858236316     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.858384468 Installing colorspace (1.4-1) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.872689164 Using cached colorspace.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.872833354     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.872990105 Installing cpp11 (0.2.1) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.885778031 Using cached cpp11.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.885943942     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.886093628 Installing crayon (1.3.4) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.898527865 Using cached crayon.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.898693673     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.898847262 Installing curl (4.3) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.912770494 Using cached curl.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.912913563     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.913086699 Installing data.table (1.12.8) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.927248401 Using cached data.table.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.927390817     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.927545426 Installing digest (0.6.25) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.939162636 Using cached digest.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.939321136     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.939474388 Installing evaluate (0.14) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.953073548 Using cached evaluate.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.953228097     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.953387847 Installing fansi (0.4.1) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.965243605 Using cached fansi.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.965403041     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.965560235 Installing farver (2.0.3) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.977484841 Using cached farver.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.977646416     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.977802573 Installing fastmap (1.0.1) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.988949470 Using cached fastmap.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.989136133     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:50.989286556 Installing foreign (0.8-71) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.001819686 Using cached foreign.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.002003425     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.002153644 Installing fs (1.4.0) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.015909878 Using cached fs.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.016060828     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.016240150 Installing generics (0.0.2) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.027809296 Using cached generics.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.027980142     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.028119112 Installing glue (1.3.2) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.040321552 Using cached glue.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.040494934     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.040658621 Installing gmp (0.6-0) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.053719938 Using cached gmp.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.053879351     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.054034889 Installing gtable (0.3.0) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.066358839 Using cached gtable.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.066508836     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.066671095 Installing highr (0.8) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.078101159 Using cached highr.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.078248476     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.078404936 Installing jpeg (0.1-8.1) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.088031942 Using cached jpeg.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.088200991     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.088352619 Installing jsonlite (1.6.1) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.100300116 Using cached jsonlite.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.100468559     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.100621599 Installing labeling (0.3) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.111192677 Using cached labeling.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.111353694     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.111510577 Installing lattice (0.20-38) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.123347726 Using cached lattice.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.123498900     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.123653307 Installing lazyeval (0.2.2) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.134118135 Using cached lazyeval.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.134279523     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.134432294 Installing leaps (3.1) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.146182526 Using cached leaps.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.146339772     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.146490596 Installing magrittr (1.5) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.156348094 Using cached magrittr.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.156497531     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.156657790 Installing mime (0.9) ... 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.167637327 Using cached mime.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.167769567     OK (symlinked cache)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:51.167921781 Installing mvtnorm (1.1-1) ... 
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=137 49ms
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=137 40ms
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=137 39ms
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=137 49ms
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=137 49ms
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:19:56.719237079 curl: HTTP 200 https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES.rds
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=138 60ms
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=138 60ms
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=138 49ms
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=138 49ms
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=138 60ms
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=138 60ms
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:20:03.114876560 curl: HTTP 404 https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/mvtnorm/mvtnorm_1.1-1.tar.gz
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:20:03.114898303 curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=140 60ms
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=140 69ms
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=140 60ms
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=140 49ms
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=140 40ms
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=140 49ms
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:20:09.709309779 curl: HTTP 404 https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/mvtnorm/mvtnorm_1.1-1.tar.gz
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:20:09.709343492 curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=142 49ms
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=142 60ms
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=142 60ms
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=142 49ms
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=142 49ms
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=142 49ms
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=142 40ms
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:20:16.284662655 curl: HTTP 404 https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/mvtnorm/mvtnorm_1.1-1.tar.gz
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:20:16.284681136 curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=144 49ms
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=144 49ms
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=144 49ms
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=144 40ms
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=144 49ms
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=144 59ms
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:20:22.829429500 curl: HTTP 404 https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/mvtnorm/mvtnorm_1.1-1.tar.gz
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:20:22.829450131 curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=146 60ms
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=146 60ms
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=146 50ms
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=146 59ms
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=146 49ms
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=146 60ms
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:20:29.409848013 curl: HTTP 404 https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/mvtnorm/mvtnorm_1.1-1.tar.gz
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:20:29.409863106 curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 
GET /__api__/tasks/IN4lmdrm0QjEiROF?first_status=148 70ms
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:20:30.412787447 FAILED
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:20:30.419285398 Error in getSourceForPkgRecord(pkgRecord, srcDir(project), availablePackagesSource(repos = repos), : Failed to retrieve package sources for mvtnorm 1.1-1 from CRAN (internet connectivity issue?)
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:20:30.419312018 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:20:30.419346065 Unable to fully restore the R packages associated with this deployment.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:20:30.419348797 Please review the preceding messages to determine which package
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:20:30.419360248 encountered installation difficulty and the cause of the failure.
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:20:30.424434886 Warning message:
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:20:30.424546636 In packrat::restore(overwrite.dirty = TRUE, prompt = FALSE, restart = FALSE) :
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:20:30.424552916   The most recent snapshot was generated using R version 3.6.0
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:20:30.419476751 Error code: r-package-not-available

[Connect] An R package required by the content cannot be found in the package repository.

[Connect] Possible causes:
[Connect] * The R package being installed is not available for the version of R configured at Connect.
[Connect] * The R package being installed is not available for linux.
[Connect] * The client computer that published the content is using a different package repository from the Connect server, and the R package being installed is not available in the repository configured at the Connect server.
[Connect] * The package repository moved to a new URL after the content was published, and Connect is now attempting to rebuild the environment using the old package repository URL.
[Connect] 
[Connect] Possible solutions:
[Connect] * Install a version of R on the Connect server that matches the one being used by the client computer. You can identify the required R version from the deployment logs, which will contain an entry similar to this:
  > Bundle requested R version 3.5.0; using /usr/lib/R/bin/R which has version 3.4.4
  In this example, the client computer has R 3.5.0 and the Connect server has R version 3.4.4. The recommended solution would be to install R version 3.5.0 on the Connect server alonside the existing 3.4.4 installation.
[Connect] * Replace usage of Windows-specific R packages with ones available for linux.
[Connect] * Configure the client with a package repository that is accessible via http(s) from the Connect server, such as CRAN or RStudio Package Manager. Reinstall the affected packages from the new repository and publish the content again.
[Connect] 
[Connect] References:
[Connect] * https://docs.rstudio.com/connect/admin/getting-started/#installation
[Connect] * https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004067074-Managing-Packages-with-RStudio
[Connect] 
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:20:30.419476751 Additional data:
[Connect] Repository: 'CRAN'
[Connect] Package: 'mvtnorm'
[Connect] PackageVersion: '1.1-1'
[Connect] Found in the following log entry:
[Connect] 2020/11/13 14:20:30.419285398 Error in getSourceForPkgRecord(pkgRecord, srcDir(project), availablePackagesSource(repos = repos), : Failed to retrieve package sources for mvtnorm 1.1-1 from CRAN (internet connectivity issue?)
[Connect] Build error: An R package required by the content cannot be found in the package repository. (r-package-not-available)
GET /__api__/applications/49/config 49ms
----- Deployment log finished at  2020-11-13 09:20:31  -----
```

My app dependencies:

```
> rsconnect::appDependencies()
Warning in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  Unable to find repository URL for package foreign
           package  version source
1               BH 1.72.0-3   CRAN
2              DBI    1.1.0   CRAN
3               DT     0.15   CRAN
4          Formula    1.2-3   CRAN
5               HH   3.1-40   CRAN
6            Hmisc    4.4-0   CRAN
7             MASS 7.3-51.4   CRAN
8           Matrix   1.2-17   CRAN
9               R6    2.4.1   CRAN
10    RColorBrewer    1.1-2   CRAN
11            Rcpp    1.0.4   CRAN
12           Rmpfr    0.8-1   CRAN
13         TH.data   1.0-10   CRAN
14           abind    1.4-5   CRAN
15         acepack    1.4.1   CRAN
16         askpass      1.1   CRAN
17      assertthat    0.2.1   CRAN
18       backports    1.1.8   CRAN
19       base64enc    0.1-3   CRAN
20           broom    0.5.5   CRAN
21           callr    3.4.3   CRAN
22      cellranger    1.1.0   CRAN
23       checkmate    2.0.0   CRAN
24             cli    2.0.2   CRAN
25           clipr    0.7.0   CRAN
26         cluster    2.0.8   CRAN
27       codetools   0.2-16   CRAN
28      colorspace    1.4-1   CRAN
29         cowplot    1.0.0   CRAN
30           cpp11    0.2.1   CRAN
31          crayon    1.3.4   CRAN
32       crosstalk  1.1.0.1   CRAN
33            curl      4.3   CRAN
34      data.table   1.12.8   CRAN
35          dbplyr    1.4.2   CRAN
36            desc    1.2.0   CRAN
37          digest   0.6.25   CRAN
38           dplyr    0.8.5   CRAN
39        ellipsis    0.3.0   CRAN
40        evaluate     0.14   CRAN
41           fansi    0.4.1   CRAN
42          farver    2.0.3   CRAN
43         fastmap    1.0.1   CRAN
44       flextable   0.5.10   CRAN
45         forcats    0.5.0   CRAN
46         foreign   0.8-71   CRAN
47              fs    1.4.0   CRAN
48         gdtools    0.2.2   CRAN
49        generics    0.0.2   CRAN
50         ggplot2    3.3.0   CRAN
51         ggrepel    0.8.2   CRAN
52            glue    1.3.2   CRAN
53             gmp    0.6-0   CRAN
54       gridExtra      2.3   CRAN
55          gtable    0.3.0   CRAN
56           haven    2.2.0   CRAN
57           highr      0.8   CRAN
58             hms    0.5.3   CRAN
59       htmlTable   1.13.3   CRAN
60       htmltools    0.4.0   CRAN
61     htmlwidgets    1.5.1   CRAN
62          httpuv    1.5.4   CRAN
63            httr    1.4.1   CRAN
64         isoband    0.2.2   CRAN
65            jpeg  0.1-8.1   CRAN
66        jsonlite    1.6.1   CRAN
67           knitr     1.28   CRAN
68        labeling      0.3   CRAN
69           later  1.1.0.1   CRAN
70         lattice  0.20-38   CRAN
71    latticeExtra   0.6-29   CRAN
72        lazyeval    0.2.2   CRAN
73           leaps      3.1   CRAN
74       lifecycle    0.2.0   CRAN
75          lmtest   0.9-37   CRAN
76       lubridate    1.7.9   CRAN
77        magrittr      1.5   CRAN
78        markdown      1.1   CRAN
79            mgcv   1.8-28   CRAN
80       microplot   1.0-42   CRAN
81            mime      0.9   CRAN
82          modelr    0.1.6   CRAN
83        multcomp   1.4-13   CRAN
84         munsell    0.5.0   CRAN
85         mvtnorm    1.1-1   CRAN
86            nlme  3.1-139   CRAN
87            nnet   7.3-12   CRAN
88         officer   0.3.13   CRAN
89         openssl    1.4.1   CRAN
90          pillar    1.4.6   CRAN
91        pkgbuild    1.1.0   CRAN
92       pkgconfig    2.0.3   CRAN
93         pkgload    1.0.2   CRAN
94           plogr    0.2.0   CRAN
95            plyr    1.8.6   CRAN
96             png    0.1-7   CRAN
97          praise    1.0.0   CRAN
98     prettyunits    1.1.1   CRAN
99        processx    3.4.2   CRAN
100       progress    1.2.2   CRAN
101       promises    1.1.1   CRAN
102             ps    1.3.2   CRAN
103          purrr    0.3.3   CRAN
104          readr    1.3.1   CRAN
105         readxl    1.3.1   CRAN
106        rematch    1.0.1   CRAN
107         reprex    0.3.0   CRAN
108       reshape2    1.4.4   CRAN
109          rlang    0.4.5   CRAN
110      rmarkdown      2.1   CRAN
111          rpart   4.1-15   CRAN
112      rprojroot    1.3-2   CRAN
113     rstudioapi     0.11   CRAN
114          rvest    0.3.5   CRAN
115       sandwich    2.5-1   CRAN
116         scales    1.1.1   CRAN
117        selectr    0.4-2   CRAN
118          shiny  1.4.0.2   CRAN
119 shinydashboard    0.7.1   CRAN
120    sourcetools    0.1.7   CRAN
121        stringi    1.4.6   CRAN
122        stringr    1.4.0   CRAN
123       survival   3.1-12   CRAN
124            sys      3.3   CRAN
125    systemfonts    0.3.0   CRAN
126       testthat    2.3.2   CRAN
127         tibble    3.0.0   CRAN
128          tidyr    1.0.2   CRAN
129     tidyselect    1.0.0   CRAN
130      tidyverse    1.3.0   CRAN
131        tinytex     0.21   CRAN
132           utf8    1.1.4   CRAN
133           uuid    0.1-4   CRAN
134            vcd    1.4-7   CRAN
135          vctrs    0.2.4   CRAN
136        viridis    0.5.1   CRAN
137    viridisLite    0.3.0   CRAN
138        whisker      0.4   CRAN
139          withr    2.2.0   CRAN
140           xfun     0.12   CRAN
141           xml2    1.3.0   CRAN
142         xtable    1.8-4   CRAN
143           yaml    2.2.1   CRAN
144            zip    2.1.1   CRAN
145            zoo    1.8-8   CRAN
```

Comment: I have this same error! Does anybody have come up with a solution for this?